# screen scrape text values from span based on other text values from corresponding span with beautiful soup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests, css-selectors

I have some beautiful soup code, like the example code below.  I'm using it to screen scrape financial data from yahoo finance about mutual funds.  In this piece of code I'm trying to scrape the "Bond Ratings" percentages, and save them in a dictionary.  I've been trying to select element values based on the span class="Fl(end)", but I'm finding that it's incorrectly pulling the text for some mutual funds for the "AAA" value.  I was wondering if there's a way instead to pull the text value for the percentage maybe using the bond name text inbetween the spans for example US Government to get the 0.00% from the corresponding 0.00%

some example code, sample data, and desired output is below.

code:

```
profile_URL='https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TRARX/holdings?p=TRARX'

profile_req = requests.get(profile_URL)

profile_soup = bs(profile_req.text)

    


bond_rating_list=['us_government_bond_perc',
        'AAA_bond_perc',
        'AA_bond_perc',
        'A_bond_perc',
        'BBB_bond_perc',
        'BB_bond_perc',
        'B_bond_perc',
        'below_B_bond_perc',
        'others_bond_perc']

        bond_rating_dct={}

        for n in range(len(bond_rating_list)):

            bond_rating_dct[bond_rating_list[n]] = dc.Decimal(profile_soup.select('span[class="Fl(end)"]')[n+5].text.replace('%',''))
```

beautiful soup sample:

```
URL='https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TRARX/holdings?p=TRARX'

req = requests.get(URL)

soup = bs(req.text)

soup
```

data:

```
<span class="Mend(5px) Whs(nw)" data-reactid="225"><span data-reactid="226">US Government</span></span></span><span class="Fl(end)" data-reactid="227">0.00%</span></div><div class="Bdbw(1px) Bdbc($seperatorColor) Bdbs(s) H(25px) Pt(10px)" data-reactid="228"><span class="Fl(start)" data-reactid="229"><span class="Mend(5px) Whs(nw)" data-reactid="230"><span data-reactid="231">AAA</span></span></span><span class="Fl(end)" data-reactid="232">0.00%</span>
```

desired output example:

```
bond_rating_dct['us_government_bond_perc'] =0.00
bond_rating_dct['AAA_bond_perc'] =50.23
```

UPDATE: I'm running beautifulsoup4            4.6.3

Comment: On the page you provided it shows that `AAA` is 0.00%. How would I get the value 50.23?

Comment: @Parzival thank you for pointing that out.  sorry I initially posted the wrong url at the top of the post.  I've updated it to match the url listed at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be a little more robust hopefully, I would move away from using classes, which tend to be dynamic, and use relationships between elements. I still use `:contains` to anchor `h3`.

I add in `session` for efficiency of tcp-re-use. I also re-factor the code to use a function, which takes a symbol as argument and returns your desired dictionary; for ease code re-use.

Here I use a mapping dictionary, to produce the keys you want, which you can extend should new elements appear in that table.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

def get_dict(symbol):
    bond_ratings = {}
    r = s.get(f'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{symbol}/holdings?p={symbol}')
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml') # html.parser
    
    for i in soup.select('div:has(> h3:contains("Bond Ratings")) [class]:nth-child(n+2)'):
        for j in i.select_one('span'):
            bond_ratings[mappings[j.span.text]] = j.parent.next_sibling.text
    return bond_ratings

mappings = { 
        'US Government': 'us_government_bond_perc',
        'AAA': 'AAA_bond_perc',
        'AA': 'AA_bond_perc',
        'A': 'A_bond_perc',
        'BBB': 'BBB_bond_perc',
        'BB': 'BB_bond_perc',
        'B': 'B_bond_perc',
        'Below B': 'below_B_bond_perc',
        'Others': 'others_bond_perc'
}

symbols = ['TRARX', 'FLCEX']

with requests.Session() as s:    
    for symbol in symbols:
        bond_rating_dct = get_dict(symbol)
        print(bond_rating_dct)
```

---

Should you decide to be more consistent in your output dictionary keys, and don't mind retrieving all items that have %s you can remove the mapping and simply use the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

def get_dict(symbol):
    bond_ratings = {}
    r = s.get(f'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{symbol}/holdings?p={symbol}')
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml') # html.parser
    
    for i in soup.select('div:has(> h3:contains("Bond Ratings")) [class]:nth-child(n+2)'):
        for j in i.select_one('span'):
            bond_ratings[j.span.text.replace(' ','_').lower() + '_bond_perc'] = j.parent.next_sibling.text
    return bond_ratings

symbols = ['TRARX', 'FLCEX']

with requests.Session() as s:   
    for symbol in symbols:
        bond_rating_dct = get_dict(symbol)
        print(bond_rating_dct)
```

Comment: thank you.  when I try your suggestion I'm getting the error below.  it seems to be related to my beautifulsoup4 version 5.6.3.  do you know how I can modify your code to work with my soup version?  error: "NotImplementedError: Only the following pseudo-classes are implemented: nth-of-type."

Comment: I would highly recommend upgrading your bs4 (4.9.3)/ soupsieve(2.2.1) to the latest versions. There is far more functionality and improvements in later versions. There is not a version 5.6.3 AFAIK.

Comment: A re-write risks losing some of the robustness I tried to build in.

Comment: sorry i mean 4.6.3.  I've been trying to update with anaconda, or install a new version but it seems to have issues.  do you know how to update it to the newer version with anaconda?  I'm running it on ubuntu server.

Comment: Afraid I don't but hopefully you will get an answer on your latest question.

Comment: thank you, your second suggestion did the trick.  I had to create a new virtual env with python 3.7.10 but after that worked great.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following `css selector` to identify parent and the child tag.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

bond_rating_list=['us_government_bond_perc',
        'AAA_bond_perc',
        'AA_bond_perc',
        'A_bond_perc',
        'BBB_bond_perc',
        'BB_bond_perc',
        'B_bond_perc',
        'below_B_bond_perc',
        'others_bond_perc']

bond_rating_dct={}
URL='https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TRARX/holdings?p=TRARX'
req = requests.get(URL)
soup=BeautifulSoup(req.text,'html.parser')
childelements=soup.select("div[class^='Mb']:contains('Bond Ratings') span[class^='Fl'][class*='end']")
for n in range(len(childelements)):
    bond_rating_dct[bond_rating_list[n]]=childelements[n].text

print(bond_rating_dct)
```

**Output:**

```
{'AAA_bond_perc': '50.23%', 'AA_bond_perc': '3.20%', 'others_bond_perc': '3.40%', 'below_B_bond_perc': '2.32%', 'BBB_bond_perc': '15.75%', 'B_bond_perc': '8.71%', 'BB_bond_perc': '8.08%', 'A_bond_perc': '8.31%', 'us_government_bond_perc': '0.00%'}
```

---

You can use regex `re` to find the parent tag and then child tag.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

bond_rating_list=['us_government_bond_perc',
        'AAA_bond_perc',
        'AA_bond_perc',
        'A_bond_perc',
        'BBB_bond_perc',
        'BB_bond_perc',
        'B_bond_perc',
        'below_B_bond_perc',
        'others_bond_perc']

bond_rating_dct={}
URL='https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TRARX/holdings?p=TRARX'
req = requests.get(URL)
soup=BeautifulSoup(req.text,'html.parser')
parentele=soup.find(text=re.compile('Bond Ratings')).find_previous('div')
childelements=parentele.select("span[class^='Fl'][class*='end']")
for n in range(len(childelements)):
    bond_rating_dct[bond_rating_list[n]]=childelements[n].text

print(bond_rating_dct)
```

Both script returns same output.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion.  I'm getting this error when running your code, I think it's related to my beautifulsoup version.  I may have issues if I upgrade my beautifulsoup version, with other modules I have installed.  error: "NotImplementedError: Only the following pseudo-classes are implemented: nth-of-type."